# Java quoted string parsing with regex

Tags: java, regex, string

Suppose I have a string

`123 --o 45 xyz 67 "abc def" " ghi jkl m" " " "" xy z`

which I need to parse into an array of strings

`["123", "--o", "45", "xyz", "67", "abc def", " ghi jkl m", " ", "", "xy", "z"]`

My straight approach to split a string by spaces (`split("\\s+")`) isn't suitable because it separates a string by spaces and doesn't consider double quotes.

But I also need to separate elements which is quoted (`" ghi jkl m"`, `"abc def"`, and `" "`).

How can I modify my regular expression in method `split` to achieve my goal?

**UPD**

We also should consider the spaces.

=> [a, "s ", abc, "", `"ad"sdsd"sdsd"`]

`"ad"sdsd"sdsd"` is a sinle element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split your input according to the below regex which uses a positive lookahead assertion.

```
String text = "123 --o 45 xyz 67 \"abc def\" \" ghi jkl m\" \" \" \"\" xy z";
String parts[] = text.split("\\s+(?=(?:\"[^\"]*\"|[^\"])*$)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Output:

```
[123, --o, 45, xyz, 67, "abc def", " ghi jkl m", " ", "", xy, z]
```

Comment: i answered these type of question n number of times. So i make this answer as CW.

Comment: But if I have an element like `a"b"c`? what about that case? I need to parsed  as a string `"a"b"c"`. We need to take into account the spaces.

Comment: yep, i would return `a"b"c`. All the above are strings.. `Arrays.toString` function convert the array elements to strings.

Answer (score 0):

or use this pattern to capture what you want

```
("[^"]+"|\S+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/176)

Comment: It doesn't split string like this `"abc def g"h"i 100" abc 100`. should be `["abc def g"h"i 100", "abc", "100"]` but I get `["abc def g"h"i", "100", "abc", "100"]`.

Comment: would you split `"abc def g " h " i 100" abc 100.` ? into `["abc def g " h " i 100", "abc", "100"]` ?